# how to do IP filtering on elastic cloud

Tags: security, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elastic-cloud

i am trying to configure ip filtering for my instance on elastic cloud.
i want to block all unallowed ip addresses to my elasticsearch and kibana.

i tried to follow this guide:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ip-filtering.html

and edit User setting overrides on my data instance.

the error i get is:
'xpack.security.transport.filter.allow': is not allowed
OR:
'xpack.security.transport.filter.enabled': is not allowed

what is the correct way to filter ip on elastic cloud?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-restrictions.html#ec-restrictions-security) document says that the ip filtering feature is not available yet for the elastic cloud service.

Consider spinning up a instance by yourself in the cloud. There are serveral cloud providers offering a elastic stack deployment and you'll benefit of the security features there.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable IP Filtering using the Elastic Cloud UI under the section "Security" of your deployment. The steps are documented in detail here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-traffic-filtering-ip.html